# jQuery Toggle parent/child tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm attempting to build a jQuery/CSS mobile menu which has expand buttons for the child ul/li tags.

The expand button works fine for "parent > child" items, but not for "parent > child > child" items or any other nested items, when I click on the expand button for a child it closes the parent.

The code I'm working with is here: http://jsfiddle.net/tbxw39hq/

```
// Mobile Menu Toggle
$(".mobile-menu li").click(function() {
    $(".sub-menu", this).toggle();
});

// Add Expand To Mobile Menu
$('.mobile-menu li:has(ul.sub-menu)').append('<div class="menu-expand">+</div>');
```

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop event propagation to child elements:

```
$(".mobile-menu li").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(">.sub-menu", this).toggle();
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qdpfuxa2/)**

Comment: Thanks that works almost perfectly! But when I expand the parent "sub-menu" all child "sub-menu" items inside it are also expanded, is it possible to click "parent 1", then click "Child 4" to expand the next menu instead of it being automatically opened with the parent?

Comment: You need to use immediate child selector as well. check the updated answer